# Unable to estimate for AR model using OLS, Yule Walker and MLE

Tags: matlab, least-squares, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood-estimation, channel-estimation

I am  learning estimation methods following the book of Steven Kay, *"Fundamentals of Statistical Processing, Volume I: Estimation Theory* "

Theory says that if the measurement noise is Gaussian, the OLS = MLE. However, in the noise-free case, why am I not getting the true estimates? I have not checked for the noisy case. Can somebody please help in correcting my code and the concept as to why none of the estimation methods such as the yule-walker, OLS and MLE are working to give the true estimates of an AR(2) model. Where am I going wrong?

```
clear
h =[1,0.195,- 0.95]; %true coeffficients
L=length(h);
N=256;
 x=round(randn(1,N)); %driving signal
 
y  = filter(1,h,x); % generate the AR(2) model
arcoeffs_yule = aryule(y ,2)
arcoeff_mle = mle(y)
Y=y';
x=x';
arcoeffs_ols =  [Y -[0;Y(1:end-1)] -[0;x(1:end-1)]]\x


arcoeffs_yule =

    1.0000    0.9285    0.0000


arcoeff_mle =

   1.0e+07 *

   -0.0941    7.8185

arcoeffs_ols =

    0.1405
   -0.1513
    0.1527
```

---

UPDATE to the code: based on the comment, I have put the length of the AR model=3 inside `aryule` instead of passing the order 2. Then I have passed some initial values to the filtered signal. Yet getting incorrect estimates.

```
   clear
    h =[1,0.195,- 0.95]; %true coeffficients
    L=length(h);
    N=256;
     x=round(randn(1,N)); %driving signal
     
y(1) = 0.1;
y(2) = 0.2;

% Generate the AR model.
for i =3 : N
    y(i) = 0.195 *y(i-1) -0.95*y(i-2) + x(i);
end

%y = filter(1,h,x);

arcoeffs_yule = aryule(y,L)
arcoeffs_mle = mle(y)
Y=y';
x=x';
arcoeffs_ols =  [Y -[0;Y(1:end-1)] -[0;x(1:end-1)]]\x

arcoeffs_yule =

    1.0000   -0.0420    0.9202    0.1261
    
arcoeffs_mle =

    0.0040    2.9161

arcoeffs_ols =
  0.1108    0.0263    0.1613
```

Comment: HI: I'm not familiar with matlab  but A) you have a 1 in h but, if it is an AR(2) that  you are generating,  then $h$ should be of length two.  B) your filter call is using $x$ which are the $\epsilon_t$ observations. You need to filter with some starting values for $x$ ( you need two because it's AR(2) ) and then call filter on those observations rather than on $\epsilon_t$. You can set the initial values to whatever you want because, for a long enough series, their effect will wear off.

Comment: Based on your suggestions, I have updated the code. Still I am getting incorrect estimates.

Comment: A) I'd have to look at the code more carefully because they shouldn't be that different but why would you have 2 AR MLE coefficients but three for OLS ?. If it's an AR(2) without intercept, you should have 2. Also, you should be getting similar but not identical estimates because the relation only holds when the underlying DGP has normal error term and is linear in x ( the standard regression model ). The AR(1) has lagged dependent variables on its RHS so  OLS  estimation, is, technically, not correct to even use for estimation. But. you can often still get quite reasonable estimates.

Comment: Hi: When you generate the simulated data, that looks correct. But I don't understand how mle or aryule functions can come back with coefficient estimates if you don't send them the underlying model ? In other words, how do they know that it's an AR(2) ? The ols coefficient code is totally greek to me unfortunately. Not clear on the \x at the end.

Comment: @markleeds: Thank you, your help in making the code workable would be extremely helpful to me. It is indeed strange that MLE gives 2 coefficients. I am not sure about the theory on normal error term.I plotted the histogram of `y` which did was not bell shaped.

Comment: For MLE, i followed the documentation https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mle.html which does not mention any other input to the function apart from the data from a normal distribution. Since my data `y` is not coming out like a bell shaped curve ( I plotted the hist(y)), is that the reason the MLE is not working?

Comment: I read  the doc. For mle, it is assuming that y is just independent data and not a function of previous $y$. So mle(y) is not going to work because you're error term is normal but the $y_t$ values are not iid. This is exactly why OLS is technically not the correct way to estimate an AR(1). Basically, what the mle(y) function in matlab assumes is not true in your case because you have an AR(1). So, don't expect mle(y) to work. You have a non-linear likelihood. It's Gaussian but the cov matrix is not the identity which is what mle(y)  assumes. Again, I'm not clear on yule or the OLS call ?

Comment: maybe mle give the 2 coefficients and ols gives the 2 coefficients and sigma ? Note that the ols coeffs should have the same problem as I described for the mle(y) call. Instead, I would look in matlab for a function that maximizes a function with unknown parameters. ( like say bfgs ).  Then, I can show you how to calculate the likelihood and you can send that in to the maximizer and get the parameters by maximizing the correct likelihood. Right now you are using a likelihood but it's not correct so when you maximize it, you get incorrect estimates.

Comment: Note that a really good text for this material is Andrew Harvey's " The Economic Analysis of Time Series". It's the best book I know of as far as getting into the nitty gritty of building likelihoods for non-straightforward models like the AR(2). His style takes some getting used to ( he's terse ) but there's a ton of info on each page if you go slowly enough and take it all in.

Comment: Why are you using MATLAB's `mle()`? It is not for AR Model Estimation.

Comment: @markleeds:  does OLS work for a Moving Average model? I was thinking of applying an inverse filtering approach then. The inverse filter for an AR model would be a truncated MA model. So if LS and MLE works for MA model, then maybe it can be applied to the inverse filter for an AR model. However I don't know how the LS would work in this case. I would have to initialize the coefficients for the inverse filter and for every initialization, the LS on the inverse filter would give an estimate that should correspond to the true estimate. Any ideas on how to approach from this angle?

Comment: No. OLS would not work for an MA model. In general, the routines for estimating MA, AR and ARMA models are not trivial because besides optimizing over the parameters, you also have to watch out to maintain the invertibility constraints ( in an AR ). But I would think that matlab would have such routines ? In general, unless you want to really get into the nitty gritty problems-subtleties, I would stay away from trying to write one yourself. Note that,  for an MA(1), AR(1) etc, it's not that difficult. But, when you get into higher order models, it's treacherous. Check out Harvey's text.

Comment: I was under the impression that LS could be applied to MA of any order by arranging the regressors in a matrix format as seen in lecture slide#14 downloaded from https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/ee/ee392m/ee392m.1056/Lecture10_Identification.pdf    Then what are the estimation methods used in time domain and where can I study about them? Journal papers mention methods for reducing the intersymbol interference due to the higher order lagged terms for channel equalization using OLS. Where can I find the basic methods for estimating AR and MA models?

Comment: As I said, generally people use the already existing functions ( in R, they are in many places ) but, IMHO, if you want to do it yourself, Harvey's text ( title of which is in one of my previous comments ) explains it most clearly. But, even with his explanations, it will  not be easy because of constraints on parameters due to needing the zeros of the characteristic equation to be inside the unit circle. Actually, AR(1) and MA(1) are straightforward . You only need Harvey.  After that, it gets more messy.

Comment: Hi: I looked at the link and the slide on page 11 where he describes an algorithm for estimating the ARMA(1,1) is wrong so I figured I'd stop there. Here's a link to more of a  summary of how the easier ones would be done. Like I said, your better off using pre-existing functions. http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~stine/stat910/lectures/12_est_arma.pdf

Comment: Hi: The same author ( stine ) has a class website which contains some R examples for estimating models such as yours ( see 12 and 13). I would think matlab should have something similar. http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~stine/stat910/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will take a look at his notes and try to understand.